# Null operators c#

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception

In `c#` we can use `??` operator like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog fap = new Dog("Phon", Sex.Male);
        Dog dog = new Dog("Fuffy", Sex.Male);
        Console.WriteLine(fap.Name ?? dog.Name);
    }
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public Dog(string name, Sex sex)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Sex = sex;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }

    public void Attack()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Sleep()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    Sex Sex { get; set; }

    void Eat();

    void Attack();

    void Sleep();
}

enum Sex
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Unknown
}
```

This way, if `fap.Name` is `null`, `dog.Name` will be the `output`.

How can we achieve with the same implementation way something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog fap = null;
        Dog dog = new Dog("Fuffy", Sex.Male);
        Console.WriteLine(fap.Name ?? dog.Name);
    }
}
```

Without getting errors if `fap` is `null`?

Comment: ```fap.Name => fap?.Name```

Comment: `fap?.Name ?? dog.Name`

Comment: Thank you, @TryingToImprove

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(fap?.Name ?? dog?.Name);` would potentially be even safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use C# 6.0 [Null propagation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

> Used to test for null before performing a member access (?.) or index (?[) operation

So:

```
Console.WriteLine(fap?.Name ?? dog.Name);
```

---

On a side note: Unless you want to make sure 100% that your object is always initialized with certain properties you can replace the "old style" constructors such as:

```
public Dog(string name, Sex sex)
{
    // Also if property names and input variable names are different no need for `this`
    this.Name = name; 
    this.Sex = sex;
}
```

With just using the object initializer syntax:

```
Dog dog = new Dog { Name = "Fuffy" , Sex = Sex.Male };
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to wait 10 mins to accept your answer, i was looking for a way to avoid the if (fap != null) use, you just gave me a way to feel better while programming in my favourite language!

Comment: @MarcoSalerno - you are welcome :) Ya! this feature was very needed and is fun to use

Comment: Yes i didn't know the existence, i will use it a lot!

Comment: Another question if i can, what should i do to apply it if i have this kind of situation: article.DataDoc = DateTime.Parse(hit.Element("DocumentDate")?.Value) ?? usedefaultvalue; ?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno - I wouldn't push it just everywhere but it's perfect for when you already see that you are writing `if(x != null) x.....`

Comment: I made this solution: article.DataDoc = DateTime.Parse(hit.Element("DocumentDate")?.Value ?? article.DataDoc.ToString());

Comment: Keep in mind that the initializer syntax cannot be used on objects with immutable properties/fields.